# Implicitly convert object to floating point type when arithmetics are performed with it

Tags: c++, c++11, implicit-conversion

Assume we have a global object `pi` and we want to implicitly convert it to either `float` or `double` depending on the context. The following does not work:

```
#include <cmath>

class Pi {
public:
    Pi() {}

    operator float() const {
        return std::atan(1.0f)*4.0f;
    }

    operator double() const {
        return std::atan(1.0)*4.0;
    }
};

const Pi pi;

#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

int main() {
    std::cout << std::setprecision(50) << pi * 1.0f << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::setprecision(50) << pi * 1.0  << std::endl;
}
```

The reason why it does not work is that the compiler does not know whether it should implicitly convert `pi` to a `float` or a `double`. However, say we always want it to convert to the type of the other operand in a binary arithmetic operator. Is there some elegant way to achieve that in C++11 or later or should I overload all arithmetic operators? Something like that:

```
class Pi {
public:
    Pi() {}

    float operator*(float x) const {
        return (std::atan(1.0f)*4.0f) * x;
    }

    double operator*(double x) const {
        return (std::atan(1.0)*4.0) * x;
    }

    //...
};
```

Or can you come up with a more elegant solution for implicitly converting the global object to an appropriate type for the context?

Comment: Depending on the context, the most elegant solution may be the one that's least confusing to code maintainers.  So rather than relying on magic, just have explicit as_float and as_double methods.

Comment: You *could* use a template in the operators, so you don't need to write each one of them: `template<typename T> T operator*(T x) const {
        return (std::atan(T{1})*T{4}) * x;
    }`

Comment: BTW, do you really need `float` version, is not `double` enough?

Comment: Yes I really need `float` and `double` version.

Answer (score 2):

Your first try is close. Let's add a templated `*` operator outside the class:

```
template<typename T>
T operator*(const Pi& pi, T&& other)
{
    return static_cast<T>(pi) * std::forward<T>(other);
}
```

And now it works. [Live Demo](http://ideone.com/fYxN7s)

---

#### Full Code

```
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

class Pi {
public:
    Pi() {}

    operator float() const {
        return std::atan(1.0f)*4.0f;
    }

    operator double() const {
        return std::atan(1.0)*4.0;
    }
};

const Pi pi;

template<typename T>
T operator*(const Pi& pi, T&& other)
{
    return static_cast<T>(pi) * std::forward<T>(other);
}

int main() {
    std::cout << std::setprecision(50) << pi * 1.0f << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::setprecision(50) << pi * 1.0  << std::endl;
}
```

Output:

> 3.1415927410125732421875 
> 3.141592653589793115997963468544185161590576171875

---

If you want to be really strict about what substitutes for `T` look into `std::enable_if` and `std::is_floating_point` within [type_traits](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/type_traits)

Answer (score 2):

Honestly, I would just stick with the path of least surprise:

```
class Pi {
    ...
    explicit operator float() { ... }
    explicit operator double() { ... }
    ...
};
```

And just cast it when you want it:

```
std::cout << std::setprecision(50) << (float)pi * 1.0f << std::endl;
```

This is just a precursor for variable templates, in which you would want just write `pi<float>`. It's the same number of characters either way.

Comment: What do you mean by variadic variable?

Comment: @user1225999 Meant [variable template](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/variable_template), just used the wrong words.

Comment: But then I would have to write `pi<float>()`?

Comment: @user1225999 Nope. Just `pi<float>`. `pi<float>()` would be called a function template named `pi`.